# In GDB on MinGW, how do I make Ctrl-C stop the program?

Tags: gdb, mingw

I'm on Windows, running GDB on an executable built under MinGW. The program has an infinite loop. I want to find it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. When I do, both the program and GDB exit. All the help on this subject seems to assume I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because GDB doesn't handle the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> event of the GUI (non-console) program properly.

You can find the workaround in *[Workaround for GDB Ctrl-C Interrupt](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Workaround_for_GDB_Ctrl_C_Interrupt)*.

---

*Update:* Given that the mingw.org domain expired, here's the code rescued from the Web Archive:

> If you find yourself trying to interrupt a program being debugged by GDB with Ctrl-C and failing then this little program will allow you to issue the break from another session. Just run it passing the Windows pid of the process being debugged and GDB will regain control. [To compile, use `gcc -o debugbreak -mno-cygwin -mthreads debugbreak.c` ]

```
/* BEGIN debugbreak.c */

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif

#if _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0501
#error Must target Windows NT 5.0.1 or later for DebugBreakProcess
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Compile with this line:

    gcc -o debugbreak -mno-cygwin -mthreads debugbreak.c

*/

static char errbuffer[256];

static const char *geterrstr(DWORD errcode)
{
    size_t skip = 0;
    DWORD chars;
    chars = FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errcode, 0, errbuffer, sizeof(errbuffer)-1, 0);
    errbuffer[sizeof(errbuffer)-1] = 0;
    if (chars) {
        while (errbuffer[chars-1] == '\r' || errbuffer[chars-1] == '\n') {
            errbuffer[--chars] = 0;
        }
    }
    if (chars && errbuffer[chars-1] == '.') errbuffer[--chars] = 0;
    if (chars >= 2 && errbuffer[0] == '%' && errbuffer[1] >= '0'
        && errbuffer[1] <= '9')
    {
        skip = 2;
        while (chars > skip && errbuffer[skip] == ' ') ++skip;
        if (chars >= skip+2 && errbuffer[skip] == 'i'
            && errbuffer[skip+1] == 's')
        {
            skip += 2;
            while (chars > skip && errbuffer[skip] == ' ') ++skip;
        }
    }
    if (chars > skip && errbuffer[skip] >= 'A' && errbuffer[skip] <= 'Z') {
        errbuffer[skip] += 'a' - 'A';
    }
    return errbuffer+skip;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HANDLE proc;
    unsigned proc_id = 0;
    BOOL break_result;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: debugbreak process_id_number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    proc_id = (unsigned) strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    if (proc_id == 0) {
        printf("Invalid process id %u\n", proc_id);
        return 1;
    }
    proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, (DWORD)proc_id);
    if (proc == NULL) {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        printf("Failed to open process %u\n", proc_id);
        printf("Error code is %lu (%s)\n", (unsigned long)lastError,
            geterrstr(lastError));
        return 1;
    }
    break_result = DebugBreakProcess(proc);
    if (!break_result) {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        printf("Failed to debug break process %u\n", proc_id);
        printf("Error code is %lu (%s)\n", (unsigned long)lastError,
            geterrstr(lastError));
        CloseHandle(proc);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("DebugBreak sent successfully to process id %u\n", proc_id);
    CloseHandle(proc);
    return 0;
}

/* END debugbreak.c */
```

> With thanks to Kyle McKay for posting the code to the cygwin mailing list http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-06/msg00321.html

Comment: Too bad you can only use the workaround to debug a Windows program. As for me, I'm debugging an Android program :(

Comment: Switching to the proper console like the one of `cmd.exe` does indeed help: I press Ctrl+C, and GDB behaves as it does on Linux. So the workaround linked to here is not that useful.

Comment: In my case, testing a programme under Windows 10 with mingw gdb, switching from powershell to cmd.exe didn't help. The proposed workaround did.

Answer (score 5):

Which "shell" are you using? If you use the MSYS "rxvt" shell, the behavior is pretty much as you describe. Ctrl-C only works if you are running from a normal Windows command prompt.

Comment: That's useful information. I'm at a Windows command prompt, and it didn't seem to work, but I'll give it another try.

Comment: You might also try "Console2". This should behave close to the Windows command prompt, but it's a lot prettier. I use gdb all the time with that, and never have any issues. https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. What solved it for me was using gdb with cmd.exe and setting the following option in gdb.

```
set new-console on
```

Now I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to interrupt both gui and console programs.

Answer (score 2):

I've just hit the same problem.

The workaround from the wiki is to run `debugbreak` with the pid of the debugged process, but `ps` doesn't show this pid, only pid of gdb. Maybe there is another way to obtain it.

But there is simpler workaround. Just start the program normally (not in gdb), check pid from `ps` and start gdb with this pid as second argument.
When gdb is attached the process stops and I can print backtrace.

Comment: Thanks. Some time ago I hit on this: Hit ^C and the debugger stops, but it stops in a different thread than the main program. If I then do info threads, it tells the thread number of the main program. Then I switch to that thread, and I can do `bt` to show the stack. I suppose it's totally obvious to anybody who really knows GDB.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works every time:

When GDB starts use this regular expression to capture the inferior process id:

```
"\[New Thread (\d+)\."
```

Then use:

```
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, PID);
DebugBreakProcess(hProcess);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

Have a look on the following GDB initialization script, it is required for this to work with MinGW on Windows 7 and later:

```
# =====================================
#  GDB preload initialization commands
# =====================================

# Set Unicode Charset
#set target-charset UCS-2
#set host-charset UCS-2
#set charset UCS-2
#set target-wide-charset UCS-2

# Set UTF-8 Charset
set target-charset UTF-8
set host-charset UTF-8
set charset UTF-8
set target-wide-charset UTF-8

# Request async target mode
set target-async 1

# Do not complain about pending breakpoints
set breakpoint pending on

# Enable All-Stop for all Threads
set non-stop off

# Do not ask for confirmations
set confirm off

# Do not create new console for output/logging
set new-console off

# Turn-off paggination to allow integration with IDE
set pagination off

# Call Stack files (and anywhere else) should be absolute path
set filename-display absolute

# Enable Pretty Print in GDB Panel
set print pretty on

# Enable notification of completion for asynchronous execution commands.
set exec-done-display on

# Show Addresses in objects, required for integration with IDE
set print address on

# Enable Pretty Print for Arrays
set print array on

# Flatten objects, required for integration with IDE
set print object off

# Include static members, required for integration with IDE
set print static-members on

# Show demangled vtable, required for integration with IDE
set print vtbl off
set print demangle on
set demangle-style gnu-v3

# Print full eight-bit characters, required for integration with IDE
set print sevenbit-strings off

# Set path for obj files
path $(TARGET_ROOT)/obj

# Load gdb scripts for STL (string, vector, map, etc.)
source $(PATH_SDK_DEBUGGER)/stl-views-1.0.3.gdb

# List of source code files
dir $(PATH_SDK_COMMON)
dir $(PATH_SDK_FRAMEWORKS)
dir $(PATH_SDK_INCLUDES)
dir $(PROJECT_PATHS.NATIVE_COMMON)

# Load the binary
file $(TARGET_OUTPUT)
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Matthew Talbert pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711086/in-gdb-on-mingw-how-do-i-make-ctrl-c-stop-the-program/1273273#1273273), this happens when GDB built with the native MinGW toolchain is used inside MSYS/Cygwin. Starting GDB with winpty worked like a charm as it's a tool designed just for that. It also worked for `cdb.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the latest **MinGW-x64** from https://www.msys2.org/ then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> just works.

```
c:\test>gdb a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1
. . .
Reading symbols from a.exe...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: c:\test\a.exe
<Ctrl>-<C>
Thread 5 received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 17312.0x5614]
0x00007ff97e75d7e3 in TlsGetValue () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\KernelBase.dll
(gdb)
```

If you're in **Cygwin**, you need to tell `gdb` to `handle SIGINT`:

```
(gdb) handle SIGINT
SIGINT is used by the debugger.
Are you sure you want to change it? (y or n) y
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        Yes       Yes     No              Interrupt
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the infinite loop, you could try stepping through the execution until you get to a sequence that repeats indefinitely.

I'm not sure, but I think Ctrl-C should only stop the execution, not gdb itself...

I think there is a "handle" command that you can use to control how the interrupt signal is handled.

Comment: I know. I was hoping not to have to do that.

Comment: You're right on both counts, but it doesn't seem to work in a Windows DOS-box.