# Unable to step through program in gdb after SIGTRAP

Tags: gdb, signals, mingw

Using mingw gdb, when I to break the program as it's running (using the method from [In GDB on MinGW, how do I make Ctrl-C stop the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711086/in-gdb-on-mingw-how-do-i-make-ctrl-c-stop-the-program)), gdb fails to pick up from there.

The only backtrace information I can get is

```
#0  0x00007fffbfccd881 in ntdll!DbgBreakPoint () from /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007fffbfcf99fb in ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin () from /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007fffbd473034 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk ()
   from /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL
#3  0x00007fffbfca1431 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

and if I try to step through the program I get

```
Single stepping until exit from function ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin,
which has no line number information.
```

and the program runs to completion. I am able to step through normally (after a breakpoint) but I can't seem to get the debugger to recover from a SIGTRAP

Comment: You are now in a new thread created only for the DebugBreak(), so you have to switch back to one of your threads. Use `info threads` for list, and switch with `thread YOUR_THREAD_NUMBER`.

Comment: @ssbssa You are correct, I just tested an it worked like a charm. Would you make it into a proper answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DebugBreakProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-debugbreakprocess) creates a new thread in the target process, which is then signalling the debugger via a breakpoint exception to pause the execution.

You can list all available threads with `info threads`, and then switch to another thread via `thread YOUR_THREAD_NUMBER`.