# Trying to use ctrl-c causes gdb to switch to TlsGetValue() and other random windows functions

Tags: c++, gdb, msys2

(Solution): The quick solution which worked for me is to enter 'info threads' and swap to thread 1, which is labeled as function ntdll!ZwDelayExecution() in ntdll.dll. Then, enter 'where', select the frame which was my program's last executed function, and then I was able to access local variables, etc.

(Original Question):

I am using gdb on Windows x64 from MSYS2 mingw64. Whenever I try to debug any C++ program (built using g++ also from mingw64) and send SIGINT using ctrl-c (on cmd.exe), I am unable to view my program's locals or use the TUI as it displays "No Source Available". I don't know if this is how it's supposed to work or not, as this still interrupts the program but at that point GDB starts viewing functions from Windows DLLs (KernelBase.dll, kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll) and I am unsure if it's possible to view my own program's data at that point.

Some sample output after pressing Ctrl-C:

```
Thread 29 received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 13216.0x2650]
0x00007ffedba21b5d in TlsGetValue () from C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffedba21b5d in TlsGetValue () from C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
#1  0x00007ffeddc17034 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
#2  0x00007ffeddea2651 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

(Edit): Doing 'info threads' results in the following:

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id           Frame
  1    Thread 16964.0x698  0x00007ffeddeed5c4 in ntdll!ZwDelayExecution () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  2    Thread 16964.0x278  0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  3    Thread 16964.0x2d0c 0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  4    Thread 16964.0x31e8 0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  5    Thread 16964.0x199c 0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  6    Thread 16964.0x254c 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  7    Thread 16964.0x25c4 0x00007ffeddeeda94 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  9    Thread 16964.0x3798 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  10   Thread 16964.0x3bd0 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  11   Thread 16964.0x2284 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  12   Thread 16964.0x3c54 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  13   Thread 16964.0x3244 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  14   Thread 16964.0x44c  0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  15   Thread 16964.0x9ac  0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  16   Thread 16964.0x3960 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  18   Thread 16964.0x3bfc 0x00007ffeddeeda94 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  19   Thread 16964.0x3144 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  20   Thread 16964.0x4038 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  21   Thread 16964.0x2e44 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  22   Thread 16964.0x2b28 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  23   Thread 16964.0x2908 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  24   Thread 16964.0x4670 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
* 25   Thread 16964.0x2e6c 0x00007ffedba21b5d in TlsGetValue () from C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
```

All of these threads appear to be from windows dlls, and I can't locate one related to my program.

However, if I haven't used ctrl-c to interrupt execution already, this is the thread information I receive:

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id          Frame
* 1    Thread 9364.0x1750 main (argc=1, argv=0x1ef61921d60) at src/system/main.cpp:76
  2    Thread 9364.0x27fc 0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  3    Thread 9364.0x44ac 0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  4    Thread 9364.0x46e8 0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  5    Thread 9364.0x190  0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  6    Thread 9364.0x2d84 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  7    Thread 9364.0x6f8  0x00007ffeddeeda94 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  9    Thread 9364.0x2804 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  10   Thread 9364.0xc50  0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  11   Thread 9364.0xc14  0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  12   Thread 9364.0x3390 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  13   Thread 9364.0x6e4  0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  14   Thread 9364.0x3bbc 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  15   Thread 9364.0x2388 0x00007ffeddef0994 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory ()
   from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  16   Thread 9364.0x1ff0 0x00007ffeddeecfc4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  18   Thread 9364.0x3c10 0x00007ffeddeeda94 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

Here I do have the option to swap to thread 1 related to my program, however thread 1 after using ctrl-c displays ntdll!ZwDelayExecution()

Comment: I think I too had this behavior. Put a breakpoint somewhere and pause on it instead.

Comment: Similar to [DebugBreakProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193032/1983398), ctrl-c creates a new thread on Windows. So switch to one of yours afterwards.

Comment: @ssbssa I've added some more output, specifically when I do 'info threads', and I can't see a thread related to my program (all seem to be from windows dlls).

Comment: `info threads` just shows you the current location of each thread, so I'm not surprised you don't see anything belonging to your program. You could check all thread backtraces with `thread apply all bt`.